# How do you scroll the page content over a cover image (like medium.com)?

Tags: css

I want to try to replicate the cover image's scroll effect found on medium.com (example: http://medium.com/@ev). As you scroll down the page, the cover photo stays fixed and the content scrolls over it, covering it up as you go. Does anyone know how to do this with CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried and had fail please. No code... we can't help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

you can do this very simply by setting the background image on a body as `fixed` and then using a `div` with no color/image as a header.

```
body{
    background: url("image.JPG") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/)

**UPDATE**

A better solution is to add it directly to the container you are targeting rather than the `body`. In this case it's the `header`

```
.header{
   background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Jefferson_Park_in_Chicago.JPG") no-repeat top center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 50px;
}
```

The results are identical but this way you don't need a container with a background color to cover up the image like the previous solution

[NEW FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/126/)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!
On more question: is there another way to do this where I can use HTML in the background image (to add buttons that look embedded in the image)

Comment: well you can put anything you want in that `.header` and it will show up on top of the image. is that what you mean?

Comment: I want to try to include a login form right on top of the image, so that it "sticks" with the image (and does't scroll away with the header text). Is that even possible? I was messing around with fixed divs and the z-index but I wasn't able to get that to work

Comment: yep, you can set the `div` to `poistion:fixed;` with a `z-index` and set (in my example) `.content` to `position: relative` with a higher `z-index`. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/1/)

Comment: great tip, exept that the first position must be on the x axis and the second the the y axis:
    background: url("image.JPG") no-repeat center top fixed;

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: I was messing around with this Fiddle to get it to do some interesting things (e.g. use vh units, add a text overlay, fade the background image so the text is more readable, etc.).  Here is the result of my effort:  https://jsfiddle.net/WsXP6/483/  There are issues with images and `background-size: cover` with a fixed position - for example, switching from landscape to portrait chops off important parts of the image as can be seen with the fish at smaller widths.  The issues go to show that choosing the right image is important.

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simply:

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

On whatever you want your fixed background on.

([example](http://jsfiddle.net/k0t4ho51/))

---

But, on behalf of my personal experience.  You could also consider a parallax scrolling library.  It makes it feel more interactive, rather than a fixed background...  There are a few JavaScript libraries to accomplish the scrolling effect (depending on how you want to trigger the effect).  But, below are a few that I prefer.

---

### [ParallaxJS](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) ([source](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax))

Creates a parallax effect based on mouse possition **or the device's gyroscope** (mobile tilting).

---

### [StellarJS](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) ([source](https://github.com/markdalgleish/stellar.js))

Creates a parallax effect based on scroll position.  This is my most favorite choice out of both, because it's based on scrolling (I believe it supports mobile scrolling too).  So you don't have to change most of your layout just to get the effect.