# Multiple background images, one cover the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My ultimate goal is to have a webpage that looks something [like this.](https://medium.com/@ev) [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/1w0kcam3/) is what I currently have.

My question is how to get the background to stick so that when the user scrolls, the rest of the text covers up the image. I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872806/how-do-you-scroll-the-page-content-over-a-cover-image-like-medium-com) and tried to play around with `background-attachment: fixed` but couldn't get anything to work, mainly because I have two backgrounds I'd like to use: the main picture (the kitten), and the texture I use for the background. I'm open to JavaScript or JQuery solutions if that's what it takes since I'm already using it for other features.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
       <li id="menu-one" class="active"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
       <li id="menu-two"><a href="#"><span>Wedding Info</span></a></li>
       <li id="menu-three"><a href="#"><span>Direcitions</span></a></li>
       <li id="menu-four"><a href="#"><span>Registry</span></a></li>
       <li id="menu-five" class='last'><a href="#"><span>RSVP</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="before_content"></div>

    <div id="item-one">

        <!--<h2 class="names" name='top'>Bob + Suzy</h2>-->

        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1000/400" alt="Snow" class="background">

    </div>

    <div id="item-two">
        <h3 class="date">Wedding Info</h3>
        <p>Paragraph 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="item-three">  
        <h3 class="date">Directions</h3>
        <p>Paragraph 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="item-four">
        <h3 class="date">Registry</h3>
        <p>Paragraph 3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="item-five">
        <h3 class="date">RSVP</h3>
        <p>Paragraph 4: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
            sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
            aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
            ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
            aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
            cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
            mollit anim id est laborum.</p>     
    </div>              

    <footer>
        <a href="#">Some footer text</a>
    </footer>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Abraham Lincoln';
    src: url(../fonts/Abraham-Lincoln/AbrahamLincoln.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ingleby';
    src: url(../fonts/Ingleby/Ingleby_regular);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Ingleby';
  background-image: url(../Images/background.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

h2.names {
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Abraham Lincoln';
}

h3.date {
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Abraham Lincoln';
}

h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Abraham Lincoln';
}

p {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.background {
    width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

footer {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(59, 58, 76);
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

footer a {
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#map-canvas {
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 200px;
}

/* ------------ */
/*   PICTURES   */
/* ------------ */

.wrapper {
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}

.grow { 
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; /* Opera */
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
    margin: 20px;
}
.grow:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1); 
    z-index: -100;
}

/* ------------ */
/*   NEW MENU   */
/* ------------ */

#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;

}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  background: rgb(43, 41, 59)   ;
  /*
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%); */
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgb(117, 144,    112 );
  width: auto;
}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  /*
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #141414));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #333333 0%, #141414 100%);
  */
  color: white;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Ingleby";
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgb(117,    144,    112 );
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  /*
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  */
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: white;
  /*
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #000000;
  */
  background: #403D57;
  /*
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #262626), color-stop(100%, #070707));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #262626 0%, #070707 100%);
  */
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0fa1e0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
  font-size: 11px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #0c7fb0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #31b7f1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #0a6d98;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

/* Make menu bar stay at top */

#cssmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var itemFour = $("#item-four");
    var position = itemFour.offset();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= $("#item-five").offset().top - 75) {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $("#menu-five").addClass('active');
        } else if (scroll >= $("#item-four").offset().top - 75) {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $("#menu-four").addClass('active');
        } else if (scroll >= $("#item-three").offset().top - 75) {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $("#menu-three").addClass('active');
        } else if (scroll >= $("#item-two").offset().top - 75) {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $("#menu-two").addClass('active');
        } else {
            $("li").removeClass('active');
            $("#menu-one").addClass('active');
        }
    });

    $("#menu-one").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#item-one").offset().top - 74
        }, 'slow');
        $("li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $("#menu-two").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#item-two").offset().top - 74
        }, 'slow');
        $("li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $("#menu-three").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#item-three").offset().top - 74
        }, 'slow');
        $("li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }); 

    $("#menu-four").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#item-four").offset().top - 74
        }, 'slow');
        $("li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

    $("#menu-five").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#item-five").offset().top - 74
        }, 'slow');
        $("li").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: you are trying to add background attachment to an image! not gonna work

Comment: @JacobGray Can I have two background images then?

Comment: P.S. not sure if you're still doing improvements, but your JS can be written all in a couple of lines (you're copy/pasting almost same functions all over the place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically:

```
<div class="imageCover" style="background-image:url(http://placekitten.com/1000/400)"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageCover{
  height:500px;
  background: none 50% / cover fixed;
}
```

Regarding your jQuery, this is all you need:

```
$(function(){

    var $menuLi = $("[id^=menu-]");
    var $itemEl = $("[id^=item-]");

    $(window).on("scroll resize", function() { // check also on resize!
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var currId = $itemEl.filter(function(i, e){ // Filter items
          return $(e).offset().top >= scroll - 75;  // retrieve a match
        })[0].id.split("-")[1];                     // get it's suffix (i.e: "two")
        $("#menu-"+currId).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    });

    $menuLi.click(function() {
        var num = this.id.split("-")[1]; // get "one", "two"...
        var y   = $("#item-"+ num).offset().top-74;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: y }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

### A better approach using `#href` to `#id`

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qosowu/4/edit)***

*Hash-Link* the Menu A HREF to the desired article ID elements like:

```
<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#home" class="active">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="imageCover" style="background-image:url(image1.jpg)"></div>
<article id="home"><h1>Home</h1><p>Content</p></article>

<div class="imageCover" style="background-image:url(image2.jpg)"></div>
<article id="home"><h1>About</h1><p>Content</p></article>

<div class="imageCover" style="background-image:url(image3.jpg)"></div>
<article id="home"><h1>Contact</h1><p>Content</p></article>
```

where i.e. the hash `href="#about"` relates to the `id="about"` `article`.

CSS:

```
nav{
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9);
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.4);
}
#menu li, #menu a{
  display: inline-block;
}
#menu  a{
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  color:#000;
}
#menu a.active{
  background: #dca;
}
.imageCover{
  height:500px;
  background: none 50% / cover fixed;
}
article{
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1140px;
}
```

than inside jQuery you watch the window scrollTop and filtering the current positions you set the *active* class to the related Menu Link:

```
var $link = $("#menu a");
var $arti = $("article");

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() { 
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    var id = $arti.filter(function(i, el){
      return $(el).offset().top >= scroll;
    })[0].id;
          $link.removeClass("active");
    $("#menu a[href$="+id+"]").addClass("active");
});

$link.click(function( e ) {
          e.preventDefault(); // Don't follow link!
    var y   = $( $(this).attr("href") ).offset().top;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: y }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks much. I'm trying to disect the JS, but I think I get the most of it. The one issue I'm having is when I scroll down, the item "Wedding Info" at the top gets highlighted too soon, as [seen here.](https://jsfiddle.net/1w0kcam3/) It works fine when you click on the `li`, but not when you scroll.

Comment: @nicholas79171 that's cause you show multiple stuff on screen, meaning the script above is not perfect at all, it just looks for the one element match. You need to take in account all the visible elements and find the most-bottom one. You got the idea.

Comment: @nicholas79171 don't be afraid to use that JS I've provided you, tweak it.  Improve it as explained above. I would also increase the space between the sections.

Comment: I'm stuck trying to get that bug worked out. The line I need to edit is `return $(e).offset().top >= scroll - 75;` correct? That retrieves the element that is just higher than the scroll position, I'm pretty sure. Except right now, it's automatically changing to "Wedding Info" as soon as I scroll down 75 pixels, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @nicholas79171 edited with a better approach. Let me know if you encounter some issues.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The one thing my code is not doing is changing the CSS on the menu bar at the top when I scroll or when I click on the link. [Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1w0kcam3/) of what I currently have. My `ul` has an `id` of `"menu"` and I try to link to it with `var $link = $("#menu a");` but I don't think that's working properly, causing the rest of my issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an illusion that will make the images position the way you want by using some parallax scroll effect. Here's one of the many links where you can find tutorials and examples on how to add a parallax effect to your elements using a combination of background fixed positions, scroll speed, etc: https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out and accept your answer if this is that I end up using!